# Symfony - render global variables in base layout

Tags: symfony, templates, controller, twig

let's assume that I'm creating a simple blog and I have two controllers - BaseController and PagesController.
In BaseController I fetching meta tags from database.
In PagesController I have two functions: index() which renders index.html.twig template and view() which renders view.html.twig.
I want to set meta tags variables from BaseController to be global so in PagesController I do not have to render them, just render variables like content which gets the data from database.

How can I do it? And what is the best solution for this?

Note: I want to do it in BaseController, I do not want to write every variable in twig global variables.

Comment: You can use: services | traits | controller inheritance | twig extension | render controller . Your question seems too broad

Comment: @goto: In BaseController I have one function which gets data from database and adds it to twig global variables using addGlobals method. In PageController I must call that function in index() and view() public functions like $base->index() - I do not want to do that, so what is the best solution?

Comment: Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, is something like this,

```
<?php
    class BaseController {

        protected function getBaseParameters() {
            /**
                Do stuff
                Do stuff
                Do stuff
            **/
            return $data;
        }

        protected function getTwig() {
            #retrieve twig instance here
            return $this->twig;
        }

        public function render($template, $args) {
            return $this->getTwig()->render($template, array_merge($this->getBaseParameters(), $args));
        }

    }


    class PagesController extends BaseController {
        public function view() {
            $args = [];
            /**
                Do stuff
                Do stuff
                Do stuff
            **/
            return $this->render('view/my/template.html', $args);
        }
    }
```